# iOS Pinch In Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, zooming

I have developed an PhoneGap based app for IPhone which works very good. The app uses IPhone PhoneGap plugin called ChildBrowser. The plugin works superb but it lacked 2 features which I wanted to code myself in objective-c to fulfill my need.

1. There has to be some function which can execute JavaScript on WebView loaded page. I have done it and it's working.
2. There is a need of a function that take 2 parameters (x and y co-ordinates) and zoom in the webpage inside webview as soon as it's finished loading.

I can create te function and all JS stuff but I am not sure how to actually perform zoom-in/pinch-out programmatically. I read about ScrollView but I am not getting it how can I get it to work with WebView. Is there any property to method in WebView (I see no) which can zoom-in the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `UIWebView`s are zoomable by default.

You can try and check whether you have this line in your html file:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable = no">
```

this will prevent zooming.

As to your first question, you can execute JS through ([look here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

```
–stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
```

and if you want to trigger some behavior when the UIWebView finished loading, then you can use the [UIWebView's delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate):

```
– webViewDidFinishLoad:
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I have already tried this one and it works fine but not on all pages. On some pages this way breaks the CSS layout of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the zoom feature of the webview should be enabled or not according what you put in the viewport meta tag of the html page header.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, user-scalable=no">`

will prevent the webview to allow zooming, you can learn more about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)